# How to declare std::unique_ptr and what is the use of it?

Tags: c++, pointers, std, unique-ptr

I try to understand how `std::unique_ptr` works and for that I found [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c17775/The-Smart-Pointer-That-Makes-Your-C-Applications-Safer--stduniqueptr.htm) document. The author starts from the following example:

```
#include <utility>  //declarations of unique_ptr
using std::unique_ptr;
// default construction
unique_ptr<int> up; //creates an empty object
// initialize with an argument
unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));
double *pd= new double;
unique_ptr<double> uptr2 (pd);
// overloaded * and ->
*uptr2 = 23.5;
unique_ptr<std::string> ups (new std::string("hello"));
int len=ups->size();
```

What is confusing to me is that in this line

```
unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));
```

We use integer as an argument (between round brackets) and here

```
unique_ptr<double> uptr2 (pd);
```

we used an pointer as an argument. Does it make any difference?

What is also not clear to me, is how pointers, declared in this way will be different from the pointers declared in a "normal" way.

Comment: `new int(3)` returns a pointer to the new `int`, just like `pd` was a pointer to the new `double`.

Comment: unique_ptr declaration is located in `<memory>` not in `<utility>`

Answer (score 125):

The constructor of `unique_ptr<T>` accepts a raw pointer to an object of type `T` (so, it accepts a `T*`).

In the first example:

```
unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));
```

The pointer is the result of a `new` expression, while in the second example:

```
unique_ptr<double> uptr2 (pd);
```

The pointer is stored in the `pd` variable.

Conceptually, nothing changes (you are constructing a `unique_ptr` from a raw pointer), but the second approach is potentially more dangerous, since it would allow you, for instance, to do:

```
unique_ptr<double> uptr2 (pd);
// ...
unique_ptr<double> uptr3 (pd);
```

Thus having *two* unique pointers that effectively encapsulate the same object (thus violating the semantics of a *unique* pointer).

This is why the first form for creating a unique pointer is better, when possible. Notice, that in C++14 we will be able to do:

```
unique_ptr<int> p = make_unique<int>(42);
```

Which is both clearer and safer. Now concerning this doubt of yours:

> What is also not clear to me, is how pointers, declared in this way will be different from the pointers declared in a "normal" way.

Smart pointers are supposed to model object ownership, and automatically take care of destroying the pointed object when the last (smart, owning) pointer to that object falls out of scope.

This way you do not have to remember doing `delete` on objects allocated dynamically - the destructor of the smart pointer will do that for you - nor to worry about whether you won't dereference a (dangling) pointer to an object that has been destroyed already:

```
{
    unique_ptr<int> p = make_unique<int>(42);
    // Going out of scope...
}
// I did not leak my integer here! The destructor of unique_ptr called delete
```

Now `unique_ptr` is a smart pointer that models unique ownership, meaning that at any time in your program there shall be only *one* (owning) pointer to the pointed object - that's why `unique_ptr` is non-copyable.

As long as you use smart pointers in a way that does not break the implicit contract they require you to comply with, you will have the guarantee that no memory will be leaked, and the proper ownership policy for your object will be enforced. Raw pointers do not give you this guarantee.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't understand anything about `model object ownership`, the `integer leak` in the code or `enforcing ownership policy for object`. Could you please suggest topics / resources to learn these concepts?

Comment: I cannot use `unique_ptr`, without getting an error: `The text ">" is unexpected.  It may be that this token was intended as a template argument list terminator but the name is not known to be a template.`, even though I have `#include <utility>` and `#include <memory>`. Any advice?

Comment: Just a minor note: `auto p = make_unique<int>(42);` instead of `unique_ptr<int> p = make_unique<int>(42);`.

Answer (score 26):

There is no difference in working in both the concepts of assignment to unique_ptr.

```
int* intPtr = new int(3);
unique_ptr<int> uptr (intPtr);
```

is similar to

```
unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));
```

Here **unique_ptr** automatically deletes the space occupied by `uptr`.

> how pointers, declared in this way will be different from the pointers declared in a "normal" way.

If you create an integer in heap space (using *new* keyword or *malloc*), then you will have to clear that memory on your own (using *delete* or *free* respectively).

In the below code,

```
int* heapInt = new int(5);//initialize int in heap memory
.
.//use heapInt
.
delete heapInt;
```

Here, you will have to **delete** heapInt, when it is done using. If it is not deleted, then memory leakage occurs.

In order to avoid such memory leaks **unique_ptr** is used, where unique_ptr automatically deletes the space occupied by heapInt when it goes out of scope. So, you need not do *delete* or *free* for unique_ptr.

Answer (score 14):

Unique pointers are guaranteed to destroy the object they manage when they go out of scope.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

In this case:

```
unique_ptr<double> uptr2 (pd);
```

`pd` will be destroyed when `uptr2` goes out of scope. This facilitates memory management by automatic deletion.

The case of `unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));` is not different, except that the raw pointer is not assigned to any variable here.

Answer (score 3):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), one of the `std::unique_ptr` constructors is

explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;

So to create a new `std::unique_ptr` is to pass a pointer to its constructor.

```
unique_ptr<int> uptr (new int(3));
```

Or it is the same as

```
int *int_ptr = new int(3);
std::unique_ptr<int> uptr (int_ptr);
```

The different is you don't have to clean up after using it. If you don't use `std::unique_ptr` (smart pointer), you will have to delete it like this

```
delete int_ptr;
```

when you no longer need it or it will cause a memory leak.