# Unique pointer still holds the object after moving

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm going through some tutorials on how smart pointers work in **C++**, but I'm stuck on the first one I tried: the *unique pointer*.  I'm following guidelines from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/).  I've also looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894400/how-to-declare-stdunique-ptr-and-what-is-the-use-of-it) already. A unique pointer is supposed to be the only pointer that has ownership over a certain memory cell/block if I understood this correctly. This means that only the unique pointer (should) point to that cell and no other pointer. From wikipedia they use the following code as an example:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(5));
std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = p1; //Compile error.
std::unique_ptr<int> p3 = std::move(p1); //Transfers ownership. p3 now owns the memory and p1 is rendered invalid.

p3.reset(); //Deletes the memory.
p1.reset(); //Does nothing.
```

Until the second line, that worked fine for me when I test it.  However, after *moving* the first unique pointer to a second unique pointer, I find that both pointers have access to the same object. I thought the whole idea was for the first pointer to be rendered useless so to speak? I expected a null pointer or some undetermined result. The code I ran:

```
class Figure {
public:
    Figure() {}

    void three() {
        cout << "three" << endl;
    }

};

class SubFig : public Figure {
public:
    void printA() {
        cout << "printed a" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<SubFig> testing (new SubFig());
    testing->three();
    unique_ptr<SubFig> testing2 = move(testing);
    cout << "ok" << endl;
    int t;
    cin >> t; // used to halt execution so I can verify everything works up til here
    testing->three(); // why is this not throwing a runtime error?
}
```

Here, `testing` has been moved to `testing2`, so I'm surprised to find I can still call the method `three()` on `testing`.

Also, calling *reset()* doesn't seem to delete the memory like it said it would. When I modify the main method to become:

```
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<SubFig> testing (new SubFig());
    testing->three();
    unique_ptr<SubFig> testing2 = move(testing);
    cout << "ok" << endl;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    testing.reset(); // normally this should have no effect since the pointer should be invalid, but I added it anyway
    testing2.reset();
    testing2->three();
}
```

Here I expect `three()` not to work for `testing2` since the example from wikipedia mentioned the memory should be deleted by resetting. I'm still printing out *printed a* as if everything is fine.  That seems weird to me.

So can anyone explain to me why:

- moving from one unique pointer to another unique pointer doesn't make the first one invalid?
- resetting does not actually *remove* the memory? What's actually happening when `reset()` is called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially you invoke a member function through a null pointer:

```
int main()
{
    SubFig* testing = nullptr;
    testing->three();
}
```

... which is undefined behavior.

From 20.8.1 Class template unique_ptr (N4296)

> 4 Additionally, u can, upon request, transfer ownership to another
>   unique pointer u2. Upon completion of such a transfer, the following
>   **postconditions** hold:
>
> - u2.p is equal to the pre-transfer u.p,
> - **u.p is equal to nullptr**, and
> - if the pre-transfer u.d maintained state, such state has been transferred to u2.d.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I see.  I was under the impression that calling a method on a null pointer would result in an exception, like Java would when calling a method on a null reference. So it's also correct when I say calling `reset()` will turn *testing* into a null pointer and again the behavior is undefined?

Comment: @Babyburger Yes, reset is similar.

Answer (score 8):

After the `std::move()` the original pointer `testing` is set to `nullptr`.

The likely reason `std::unique_ptr` doesn't check for null access to throw a runtime error is that it would slow down every time you used the `std::unique_ptr`. By not having a runtime check the compiler is able to optimize the `std::unique_ptr` call away entirely, making it just as efficient as using a *raw pointer*.

The reason you didn't get a crash when calling the `nullptr` is likely because the function you called doesn't access the (non-existent) object's memory. But it is *undefined behavior* so anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

On calling `std::unique_ptr<int> p3 = std::move(p1);` your original pointer `p1` is in undefined state, as such using it will result in undefined behavior. Simply stated, never ever do it.

Comment: No the original is required to hold a nullptr. (See: 20.8.1 Class template unique_ptr)

Comment: @Dieter, Wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: I think "unspecified" is a better description of what you were trying to say.