# Calling class functions from constructor or use smart pointers?

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

I have a class which handles many of huge search process (Start, stop,... etc).

```
class CSearch
{
 public:
   CSearch();
  ~CSearch();

   bool Start();
   bool Stop();
};
```

I'm a little bit confused for calling `Start` function from this way:

```
CSearch search;
search.Start();
```

Or this:

```
std::unique_ptr<CSearch> search(new CSearch);
search->Start();
```

I have no idea about the diffrence Or it affect performance?

Which is better and why? (Question is not about the only unique_pointer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare std::unique\_ptr and what is the use of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894400/how-to-declare-stdunique-ptr-and-what-is-the-use-of-it)

Comment: Without knowing the full context, I would say using pointers (smart or not) is probably not the right solution to whatever problem you have.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited my post, I have The class above. `Start` function will search a string in files. But I don't know should I use the Constructor or Remove it and use Smart Pointer instead. What is different?

Comment: Constructors have nothing to do with smart pointers. Whether one uses a smart pointer, or not, there's always a constructor. Again: this cannot be fully explained in one or two sentences. The full explanation will be in your C++ book.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok I will check that

Comment: Please break this question into smaller, more specific questions. There are specific answers dealing with [performance of smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22295665/1460794) for example. The way this question is currently written "performance or something...", "question is not about the only unique_ptr", makes it seem like a long rambling answer is required and that doesn't quite fit the SO format.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't explain why do you really need pointers then don't use them.

Here's quick read from Stroustrup: [5.2 Resource Management](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&dq=concurrency%20and%20utilities%20c%2B%2B%20programming&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFm8-C6dnWAhXDx4MKHc0yAQMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=concurrency%20and%20utilities%20c%2B%2B%20programming&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Which is better, a mountain bike or a road bike?

Both of those have situations where they are better, although in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or better I'd use make unique instead of a wrapped new there.

As a general rule, unless you need dynamic lifetime ir allocation for a soecific reason, automatic storage is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ core guidelines advise that scoped objects (local objects, global objects,  or members) should be preferred to heap allocation.

In terms of performance, using scoped variables implies that there is no separate allocation and deallocation cost in excess of that already used for the containing scope or object.

The above is taken from here: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-scoped

You can find further guidelines on resource management here:
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-resource