# Generic vector class using smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying (struggling) writing a generic vector class using std::unique_ptr. In my constructor I get this exception thrown:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
std::unique_ptr<int [0],std::default_delete<int [0]> >::operator[](...) returned nullptr.
```

This is the associated function:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int n, const T &value) {
    capacity = (n > initial_capacity) ? n : initial_capacity;
    size = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = value;
    }
}
```

I also get an error here in the main.cpp file:

```
assert(nullVector.getCapacity() == 100);
```

I believe this is because I did not set the capacity in the std::unique_ptr if that is even possible.

Here is part of my header file:

```
#ifndef Vector_h
#define Vector_h



template <class T>
class Vector {
private:

    static constexpr int initial_capacity = 100;

    // Instance variables
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data = nullptr;

    void deepCopy(const Vector<T> &source) {
        capacity = source.size + initial_capacity;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.size; i++) {
            data[i] = source.data[i];
        }
        size = source.size;
    }

    void expandCapacity() {
        auto oldData = std::move(data);
        capacity *= 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = oldData[i];
        }
    }

public:

    // Constructors
    Vector() = default;                                 // empty constructor
    Vector(int n, const T &value);                      // constructor
    Vector(Vector<T> const &vec);                       // copy constructor
    Vector<T>& operator=(Vector<T> const &rhs);         // assignment operator

    // Rule of 5
    Vector(Vector<T> &&move) noexcept;                  // move constructor
    Vector& operator=(Vector<T> &&move) noexcept;       // move assignment operator
    ~Vector();                                          // destructor

    // Overload operators
    T& operator[](int index);
    T const& operator[](int index) const;
    bool operator==(const Vector<T>&) const;

    //Vector<T>& operator+=(const Vector<T> &other) {
    //  Vector<T> newValue(size + other.size);

    //  std::copy(this->data, this->data + this->size, newValue.data);
    //  std::copy(other.data, other.data + other.size, newValue.data + this->size);

    //  newValue.swap(*this);
    //}

    friend Vector<T>& operator+(Vector<T> &source1, Vector<T> &source2) {
        int n = source1.getSize() + source2.getSize();
        Vector<T> newSource(n,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < source1.size; i++) {
            newSource[i] = source1[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < source2.size; i++) {
            newSource[i + source1.getSize()] = source2[i];
        }

        return newSource;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, Vector<T> &data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(Vector<T> &other) noexcept;
    void display(std::ostream &str) const;
    int getSize() const { return size; }
    int getCapacity() const { return capacity; }
    bool empty() const { return size == 0; }
    void clear() { size = 0; }
    T get(int index) const;
    void set(int index, const T &value);
    void set(int index, T &&value);
    void insert(int index, const T &value); 
    void insert(int index, T &&value);
    void remove(int index);
    void push_back(const T &value);
    void pop_back();

};



template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int n, const T &value) {
    capacity = (n > initial_capacity) ? n : initial_capacity;
    size = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Here is part of the main.cpp file:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <ostream>
#include "Vector.h"


int main() {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// VECTOR //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Vector<int> nullVector;                        // Declare an empty Vector
    assert(nullVector.getSize() == 0);                 // Make sure its size is 0
    assert(nullVector.empty());                    // Make sure the vector is empty
    assert(nullVector.getCapacity() == 100);          // Make sure its capacity is greater than 0


}
```

Comment: You aren't calling that constructor, you're calling the empty constructor (at least in the code you posted).

Comment: Please don't post commented-out code - it makes it hard to know what you are actually asking about.

Comment: please create a minimalist version of your code to make it easier to debug. Take out all unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "capacity" of a `unique_ptr`. All an [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does is it holds on to a dynamically allocated object. It does not allocate an object by itself. Use [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) or `new` to create an new object and assign to your `unique_ptr` to hold on to.

I don't see you allocating any memory anywhere in your code. Unless you do allocate memory for your vector somewhere in a piece of code you didn't show, your `data` will just point to `nullptr` and trying to dereference it will crash (or worse). At least your `expandCapacity()` method does not seem to allocate any memory…

You probably should have a look at some material to learn about `unique_ptr` and smart pointers in general. For example: [How to declare std::unique_ptr and what is the use of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894400/how-to-declare-stdunique-ptr-and-what-is-the-use-of-it) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-unique-ptr-instances).

Comment: void expandCapacity() {
  auto oldData = std::move(data);
  capacity *= 2;
  data = std::make_unique<T>(capacity);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   data[i] = oldData[i];
  }
 }

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still does not work