# Trouble with operator "=" when assigning a unique_ptr<>

Tags: c++, object, abstract-class, unique-ptr

In this code, `Payment` is an abstract base class of `Credit`. Any idea how to fix this assignment?

> binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Credit *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p;
Credit c("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99);
p = &c;
```

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894400/how-to-declare-stdunique-ptr-and-what-is-the-use-of-it

Comment: You're lucky. If that had succeeded the program would have deleted `c` twice.

Comment: Good question, and an easy mistake to make starting out with smart pointers. When you declare a local variable, you can think of it as though the function "owns" the variable. So if you want the `unique_ptr` to own it, you need to construct it inside the pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo — the program would have **deleted** the object once and **destroyed** it twice.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I agree. Sloppy wording on my part.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::make_unique` here:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Payment> p = std::make_unique<Credit>("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99);
```

Remember that `unique_ptr` takes ownership of the pointer you give it. In your code, you allocate `c` as a local variable, so giving a raw pointer to that variable to a `unique_ptr` will cause the variable to be `delete`d, which is illegal.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response. makes_sense haha.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the `Credit` object using the [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) operator so that `unique_ptr` can `delete` it later.  You are declaring `c` as a local variable, not via `new`.  So even if the code could *compile*, it would not *behave* correctly at runtime.

`std::unique_ptr` does not have an [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) that takes a *raw pointer* as input, only another `unique_ptr`.  That is why you are getting the compiler error.

If you have only a raw pointer available, you can use the [`unique_ptr::reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) method, eg:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p;
...
Credit *c = new Credit("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99);
p.reset(c);
```

But it is better to not use a raw pointer at all, it should be wrapped in a `unique_ptr` from the very beginning, eg:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p(new Credit("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99));
```

Or:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p = std::make_unique<Credit>("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99);
```

If you want to declare and assign `p` separately, you can do that too, eg:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p;
...
p = std::unique_ptr<Payment>(new Credit("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99));
```

Or:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Payment> p;
...
p = std::make_unique<Credit>("<cardnumber>", "<expdate>", 9999.99);
```